# SQL Reporting Service SSRS PDF Export Missing the Bookmarks?

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, bookmarks

I'm using SSRS 2008, and in visual studio during preview, then save to pdf. the bookmarks don't export, or atleast the PDF reader dosn't think there are any (in Adobe Reader, click Document - Navigation - Bookmark (but bookmarks is missing))

Has anybody ever exported thier SSRS bookmarks with the report? And had them working?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the DocumentMapLable available in Properties.

Here's the documentationf or PDF export for SSRS 2008 R2

Document Map
If there are any document map labels present in the report, a document outline is added to the PDF file. Each document map label appears as an entry in the document outline in the order that it appears in the report. In Acrobat, a target bookmark is added to the document outline only if the page it is on is rendered.

If only a single page is rendered, no document outline is added. The document map is arranged hierarchically to reflect the level of nesting in the report. The document outline is accessible in Acrobat under the Bookmarks tab. Clicking an entry within the document outline causes the document to go to the bookmarked location.

Bookmarks
Bookmarks are not supported in PDF rendering.